# Считается ли повторение формы слова "лексическим повтором"

Tags: лексика

Считается ли в ЕГЭ повторение слов в разных формах лексическим повтором?
Например: "Я жил в доме. Дом сам по себе был очень красивый, большой, уютный". Или считается, что тут связь предложений посредством "форм слова".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Как известно, повтор может быть **средством связи** предложений, а также средством **художественной выразительности**. В то же время неоправданный повтор может считаться **стилистической ошибкой**.

[Лексический повтор — это стилистическая ошибка](https://vk.com/wall-166993436_8668)

[Речевые повторы: избавляемся, но без фанатизма](https://dzen.ru/media/probel/rechevye-povtory-izbavliaemsia-no-bez-fanatizma-5d8cf6ae80879d00afe35091)

Повтор слова для грамматической связи должен быть **не очень заметным**, в то время как художественный повтор автор старается **выделить**.

2. Рассмотрим пример: **Сельский букет** стоял на круглом столе. Лет десять назад **такой букет** не поставили бы на стол (Ю. Тынянов).

Слово "букет" повторяется, но при этом используются **разные определения**, в том числе местоимение ***такой***; также между словами **нет прямого контакта**. Тогда это оправданный лексический повтор для грамматической связи предложений, который нормально воспринимается на слух.

3. *Я жил **в доме. Дом** сам по себе был очень красивый, большой, уютный.*

В данном случае у нас повтор **рядом** расположенных слов, поэтому в первое предложение можно добавить определение (это надо смотреть по контексту). Также можно изменить порядок слов во втором предложении.

Редактирование: *Я жил **в доме напротив**. Сам по себе **дом** был очень красивый, большой, уютный.*

Comment: Sharon, вы забыли добавить к отсутствию прямого контакта самое главное! Это слово "такой". Без него, и даже когда нет контакта, может резать слух повторение. А со словом "такой", конечно, только "букет" возможен, не скажешь же "такой его". Если я правильно понимаю, "такой" именно и придаёт эту выразительность второй фразе.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем. Я имела в ввиду, что "такой" является  ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕМ для слова "букет" во втором предложении. Но вообще говоря, его нужно выделить, так как местоимение – это универсальное определение, которое часто используется в предложениях с повтором (такой, этот),  А здесь это очень важно и для смысла.

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать конкретный ответ. Раз вы в этом примере увидели "лексический повтор", значит формы слова (именно на ЕГЭ) тоже считаются лексическом повтором?

Comment: Артем, у меня вроде написано раздельно "в виду"

Comment: @Ajgy  Формы слова однозначно считаются лексическим повтором - это всего лишь формы одного и того же слова. Повтор однокоренных слов  относят к тавтологии.  Лексический повтор, тавтология и плеоназм  – речевая избыточность, если они не имеют определенной функции.  Именно на ЕГЭ?  Этого я не могу вам сказать. Но было бы странно, если на ЕГЭ особая правильность, отличная от общепринятой.

Comment: Из ответов Грамоты.ру. Тавтологию (употребление однокоренных слов) обычно отличают от лексического повтора (повтора одного и того же слова). В Вашем предложении тавтологией можно назвать встречу местоимений твой и тебя. Дважды употребленное тебя — это лексический повтор.  Лексический повтор: Красные зори,
Красный восход,
Красные речи у Красных ворот
И красный на площади Красной народ.

Comment: Я про комментарий, в ответе такого даже и нету вроде.

Comment: Интересный вариант.  Я вроде бы смотрела комментарий, там было раздельное письмо, а сейчас вижу что слитное.  Я сначала написала слитно, но тут же исправила предложение, даже еще не отправляя комментарий.  Просто мистика какая-то. Как будто система печатает,  как сама хочет

Comment: Да уж, неприятно( И вправду мистика!)))

Answer (score 0):

Да, считается лексическим повтором, как и в примере с сайта https://russkiiyazyk.ru/leksika/leksicheskiy-povtor.html, где слово имеет разные падежи:

> Сельский букет стоял на круглом столе. Лет десять назад такой букет не
> поставили бы на стол (Ю. Тынянов).

Comment: Но постойте! В примере с сайта это средство выразительности, как верно сказано!